# Update two columns in a query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have one php website in which when press one action button called Activate...

I am changing value of column from 0 to 1 with query. I want also change time stamp from other column `qu_time` with current time stamp.

My query is like below

```
$upd_qry = "update tbl_quotes 
            set qu_status='".$_GET['status']."' 
            where id='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
```

What should I do for update column `qu_time` with current time stamp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comma(`,`) to update multiple fields in an SQL query. Also, to get the current timestamp, you can use the SQL function `NOW()`.

Combine these and you can do something like this:

```
$upd_qry = "update tbl_quotes 
    set qu_status='".$_GET['status']."', qu_time=NOW()              
    where id='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
```

Comment: This is working fine...I will accept this answer... Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
"update tbl_quotes set qu_status='".$_GET['status']."',qu_time=sysdate() where id='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
```

Try above code.

hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `date()`

```
"update tbl_quotes set qu_status='".$_GET['status'].",qu_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s') where id='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
```

Comment: You might want to check the syntax there my friend

Comment: You might want to check the syntax AGAIN there my friend

Comment: Maybe you should give up